# Finding mean duration(H:M:S) in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean

I am trying to find the mean duration in a pandas dataframe.  I have tried the following code and receive the error:

```
TypeError: Could not convert 1:10:4200:38:5800:42:142:30:4100:19:22 to numeric
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

duration=['1:10:42','38:58','42:14','2:30:41','19:22']
dist=[8,5,6,17,3]
dd=list(zip(duration,dist))
df=pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['duration','dist'])
print(df)
print('')
max_dist=df['dist'].max()
mean_dist=df['dist'].mean()
df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(lambda x: x if len(str(x)) ==7 else '00:'+str(x)) 
print(df['duration'])
pd.to_datetime(df['duration'],format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
max_duration=df['duration'].max()
mean_duration=df['duration'].mean()
print('')
print('max dist =',max_dist,'ave dist =',mean_dist)
print('max duration =',max_duration,'ave duration =',mean_duration)
```

The max duration returns the correct value.  Does the error message mean that the datetime format cannot be used for the mean or is there another way that I'm missing?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can accept only one answer, but you can upvote more if you want... ;-)

Comment: And @Kurt instead of using `apply` its better you go for MaxU's approach. It will be really fast on the long run.

Comment: @Bharath shetty thanks for the input.  I'm still pretty new to python/pandas and at this point I'm still going with what's easiest for me to understand.   These are 3 great answers and I'll have to experiment with them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to convert the `duration` column to a `timedelta` column

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])
```

Then, this would return no errors

```
mean_duration=df['duration'].mean()
```

Answer (score 4):

Demo:

```
In [78]: s = pd.Series(['1:10:42','38:58','42:14','2:30:41','19:22'])

In [79]: s
Out[79]:
0    1:10:42
1      38:58
2      42:14
3    2:30:41
4      19:22
dtype: object

In [80]: s[s.str.match(r'^\d+\:\d+$')] = '00:' + s

In [81]: s
Out[81]:
0     1:10:42
1    00:38:58
2    00:42:14
3     2:30:41
4    00:19:22
dtype: object

In [82]: t = pd.to_timedelta(s)

In [83]: t
Out[83]:
0   01:10:42
1   00:38:58
2   00:42:14
3   02:30:41
4   00:19:22
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [84]: t.mean()
Out[84]: Timedelta('0 days 01:04:23.400000')
```

Comment: I think regex would not be necessary when using `to_timedelta`

Comment: @Bharathshetty, `pd.to_timedelta` (Pandas 0.20.3) gives me `ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format` if i don't convert it to `hh:mm:ss` format...

Comment: @Bharathshetty, how did you get `df['duration']`?

Comment: You got my vote for that haha. I thought you assigned `df['duration']` to `duration`. Your answer is far far better

Comment: @Bharathshetty, now i got it. It was confusing... Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Voting up for the regex wizardry :)

Answer (score 4):

Assign after `pd.to_timedelta` and find mean i.e

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])
print('max duration =',max_duration,'ave duration =',df['duration'].mean())
```

Output:

```
max duration = 02:30:41 ave duration = 0 days 01:04:23.400000
```